# Will randomly reading duplicate SQLite files improve read performance?

Tags: php, sql, database, performance, sqlite

This is probably common sense but just want to make sure.

As the [manual](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) says, SQLite can theoretically cater up to 1,000,000 hits/day. Now if I'm using SQLite only to read data, and if I make 3 copies (for example) of my database file, then read those randomly, will it theoretically increase performance up to 3,000,000 hits or will it gain nothing since it's using the same library/code?

Example:

```
$choices[1] = 'db1.db';
$choices[2] = 'db2.db';
$choices[3] = 'db3.db';

$random = rand(1, 3);
$db_file = $choices[$random];

$db->read($db_file);
```

Comment: The manual talks about 100k hits/day, not 1 mil. This is a rough estimate, as it depends very much on how many and how complex SQLite operations you perform per hit. This is also a very conservative estimate, as 100k/day comes to an average of 1.15 hits per second, which is not much by any standard, but they are probably taking into account usage peaks. I doubt you will gain much performance by distributing the load between three local files, since reading threads should not block each other anyway.

Comment: @lanzz The manual says `SQLite has been demonstrated to work with 10 times that amount of traffic.` so it's 100k x 10 = 1M

Comment: This does not mean that it was reaching any limit at that point, it might be just the peak usage with capacity to spare. Are you hitting any performance issues at all, or is this a theoretical question? 1 mil hits/day is already a lot of traffic.

Comment: @lanzz Both performance and theoretical. I am using MySQL right now and I'm considering using SQLite if it will decrease server load.

Comment: I doubt switching to SQLite is going to be helpful. The (very old) [SQLite speed comparison](http://www.sqlite.org/speed.html) document seem to show very similar read performance between MySQL and SQLite. Both engines have been in active development since, so perhaps they might be faster now than then, but I doubt SQLite has managed to overtake MySQL by any significant amount.

Comment: Also SQLite does not handle high concurrency well (an update to a single table will block any other read or update to the entire database); this might or might not worsen your performance.

Comment: If `db1.db`, `db2.db` and `db3.db` run on the same server and the same storage instance, then it can happen that you `theoretically` only get `1,000,000 hits/day / 3` because you have a lot overhead. For example your OS Filecache have to do the same data caching 3x times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect it to make your performance worse, not better, because you'd be putting more pressure on the file system cache.

In fact, it could be far worse than just a third the speed. Consider the case where your database is about the same size as your available RAM and each query requires scanning the whole database. If you have just one copy, the cost of a query is the time to scan all of memory. If you have three copies and choose which one to use randomly, the average cost of a query can be as high as two-thirds the time to read the whole database from disk (depending on access patterns and the cache's eviction policy). And disk is many orders of magnitude slower than memory.

See also [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29).